# hCaptcha JavaScript API render: invalid container 'null'

Tags: javascript, api, recaptcha, captcha

I'm getting this error <**[hCaptcha] render: invalid container 'null'.**> on opera developer console.
I replaced my site key and it returned invalid container null.

Here is my source code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://hcaptcha.com/1/api.js?onload=yourFunction&render=explicit" async defer></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var yourFunction = function () {
          console.log('hCaptcha is ready.');
          var widgetID = hcaptcha.render('captcha-1', { sitekey: 'MY_SITE_KEY' });
        };
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="h-captcha" data-sitekey="MY_SITE_KEY" data-theme="dark"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `render` is called **implicitly**, the default `containerId` is `h-captcha`, as defined in the `class` of the target div.

When you call `hcaptcha.render()` **explicitly**, the first parameter is the `containerId`.

Due to this behavior, your problem can be resolved by either changing your first parameter of your `render()` call to `h-captcha` rather than `captcha-1`, or changing the `class` value to `captcha-1`.

Comment: If someone was tried like me change class and id to h-captcha it will be work. Thanks for your help Claies (: